# Is it possible to have two client side web pages communicate in different browsers but the same domain?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, websocket, socket.io-1.0

I am currently working on a demo simulation. Where upon a user presses a button on a mobile styled app and in a different browser a taxi comes to collect them using the google maps api. Both are client side.

I want both the mock phone web app and google maps simulation to trigger event which change what is displayed on either. Currently I plan on using a rest express api as buffer. Both the phone app and the google maps sim will make settimeout get requests to the api.

Is this possible? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you'd better use a websocket for that... You can look at any demo for making an instant messaging system using sockets to give you some directions

Comment: Use https://socket.io/ and you can do this in real-time instead of using `setTimeout` (and please don't add tons of unrelated tags to your questions)

Comment: Checkout if Openshift is a solution for you so you can start as much pods with your client as you need.

Comment: yes of course, via the server

Comment: Seen facebook chat? Or...almost any chat, on a website really. Or even this site. That's two browsers communicating on the same domain. Just how we do right now via me writing a comment and you probably got a notification for it. So, it's possible.

Comment: you can look at multiple options: web sockets, rtmp, webRTC